# getting control names of another exe

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

Hello all i have a rather specific Question and please consider my apologies if this is not a standard stack-overflow question , 
i need to know is it possible to get all control names of another exe e.g.

i have a c# application and i want to get all control names of another standalone application running on my computer say b.exe so if b.exe have a textbox and a button in it i want to have names of textbox and button in my c# exe and also i want to have a listener for click events of b.exe

till now whatever i have researched is nothing special actually i dont want full code snaps i just want a guideline can i do it thorugh pinvoke? or winapi? please explain what is pinvoke and winapi and is it possible through application hooking ? once again i need a guideline a way to follow so please help me out regarding this, i know i can get active windows name through pinvoke or winapi but my requirements are little high

Comment: What is your actual goal. You are not, I presume, interested in knowing some names just for the sake of it. And what GUI framework was used for the target app?

Comment: my goal is to get names  of all controls in a window, and if it is not possible than i will have to go with some other property like location of each control and for time being i am using only .Net Apps

Comment: You are looking for [Microsoft Active Accesibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373592.aspx).

Comment: .net is not a GUI framework. Controls don't always have names. Controls don't always have windows. And UIAutomation is a better choice than MSAA.

Comment: Your goal to get all control names for a generic app is not possible to realise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 . Access to control names:

Unfortunately I do not .NET (C#) but under Visual C++ this would be impossible.

The reason is: The controls do not have names in the executable any longer but the names are simply converted to numbers.

Example "myTextControl" would be 1234 in the executable. The information about the (original) name of the control gets completely lost while compiling.

2 . Accessing controls in other executables:

I think under .NET (C#) it is not as easy as under native programming languages (directly accessing the Windows API) but it is possible to access controls of other executables as long as you know the number (e.g. 1234).

Therefore you'll have to find out the window handle of the dialog window containing the control and then you can send messages to the control. Unfortunately many messages containing pointers will require some very tricky hacks. Messages without pointer work well.

3 . Creating a listener for a control in other executables:

Creating a listener (e.g. a click listener) on a control in another EXE is possible however very tricky: This would require writing a native (this means: not .NET / C#) DLL file which is then combined with the Windows API function "SetWindowsHookEx".

I do not think that a .NET API (required for C#) already exists that will do this because there are only few use cases for this.

Comment: ok thank you martin for your valuable time ,but i think we can still access controlname under c#,and lets see if it is impossible to get controls name but i think still i can get number of controls on a form lets say if i have one textbox and one button i can count them which is of course 2 , and also having click listener is something i thought would be easy enough but lets see if some one can point me out to it

Comment: ok i am here after some work done i used spy++ tool of visual studio and there i can see my window and under my main window i can also see my controls in spy++ but all my controls are being treated as child windows so i am getting some where and also if i have a button say button1 i can get its caption same is for labels and textboxes , and when i do click on button1 it sends a message infact bunch of messages to spy++ so my real concern now are can i see it is a click or some thing else?

Comment: What spy++ does is exactly using the "SetWindowsHookEx" function. If you want to listen for control element events you'll have to watch for WM_COMMAND messages on the parent window (not the control itself).